# How to call a function with a compile time collection of types and iterate them?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got the following code which demonstrates my issue:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class IBaseClass
{
public:
    virtual ~IBaseClass() {}
};

class Foo final : public IBaseClass
{
public:
    static inline const std::wstring kClassName = L"Foo";
};

class Bar final : public IBaseClass
{
public:
    static inline const std::wstring kClassName = L"Bar";
};

template<typename T>
static std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> test(const std::wstring& className)
{
    if (T::kClassName == className)
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename... Args>
static std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> test(const std::wstring& className)
{
    // Call above test() with first type
    auto pAction = test(className);
    if (pAction)
    {
        return pAction;
    }
    // It didn't match - how do call it again with the next type and bail if we're out of types ??
    test<Args...>(className);
}

void doTest()
{
    test<Foo, Bar>(L"Foo");
}
```

How do I get the iteration of the types to work here? Or is there a better way to do this? I want to call test() with the single type for every type passed into the varadic test until there is a match or we run out of types.

Compiler output is:

```
    <source>: In function 'std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> test(const wstring&) [with Args = {Foo, Bar}]':

<source>:43:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

   43 | }

      | ^

<source>: In function 'std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> test(const wstring&) [with Args = {}]':

<source>:43:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

   43 | }

      | ^

Compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: What is the error message from the compiler?

Comment: You may want to read up more on parameter packs - if you want to iterate over a set of templated arguments, you need to peel one off.   There is also nothing in the last definition of (templated) `test()` that forces the compiler to call the previously templated `test()`, so your calls of `test()` are either ambiguous (no way for the compiler to resolve the type where `auto` is used) or infinitely recursive (passing the argument passed directly to the same function).

Comment: Implementation aside - what return type do you imagine the second `test` should have? How do you plan to actually use it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I may have messed up my example on the return type actually. I was going to say std::unique_ptr<T> which can't work for multiple types. However in my "real" code there is a common base type that it would return, so std::unique_ptr<CommonBaseOfFooAndBar>

Comment: OK - I've updated my code/compiler output now that there is a fixed return type and it actually builds! I guess now I need to figure out this " if you want to iterate over a set of templated arguments, you need to peel one off" part.

Comment: With sufficiently modern compiler, you don't need recursion. You can write something like `template<typename... Args>
static std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> test(const std::wstring& className)
{
    std::unique_ptr<IBaseClass> result;
    ((className == Args::kClassName && (result = std::make_unique<Args>())) || ...);
    return result;
}` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3aJyD8). This uses a C++17 feature though.